# Webpack Compilation Error with Typescript and JSForce

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, salesforce, cypress

I am using JSForce with Typescript with CypressIO however each time i attempt to run my code i receive the following:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/csv-parse/lib/es5/sync.d.ts 3:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import * as csvParse from './index';
| 
> export = parse;
| 
| declare function parse(input: Buffer | string, options?: csvParse.Options): any;
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/csv.js 5:19-52
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/record-stream.js
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/core.js
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/jsforce.js
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/index.js
 @ ./cypress/test/test.ts

./node_modules/csv-parse/lib/es5/index.d.ts 7:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import * as stream from "stream";
| 
> export = parse;
| 
| declare function parse(input: Buffer | string, options?: parse.Options, callback?: parse.Callback): parse.Parser;
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/csv.js 4:15-43
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/record-stream.js
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/core.js
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/jsforce.js
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/index.js
 @ ./cypress/test/test.ts
```

I have installed `@types/jsforce`. I have also installed `ts-loader` and `json-loader` (was a potential solution i saw) however no luck. My webpack config currently looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".d.ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    options: { transpileOnly: true }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.d\.ts$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    options: { transpileOnly: true }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: "raw-loader",
                    options: { transpileOnly: true }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: "json-loader",
                    options: { transpileOnly: true }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    target: 'node',
    mode: "development"
};
```

I am importing jsForce like `const jsforce: any = require('jsforce');`. I'm not sure what other loader I should be using here.

Comment: The error is coming out of a `.d.ts` file in `node_modules`, which you have ignored in your webpack config.  Try removing `node_modules` from the `exclude` for `.d.ts` files, or to be more specific, try including only the `csv-parse` module.

Comment: Correct, this was part of the fix. It was a complete oversight on my behalf. I had to modify a couple other things in my code since I needed them excluded but all is well now. Thank you!